# How to get the sum of numeric column in Ent

Tags: go, m2m, ent

I have two tables: `products` and `baskets`, which have the `M2M` relation and the table name is `basket_products`. I am trying to get the specific basket-related `products` total `price` and quantity, but I am getting stuck again. How can I fix the following code to get the result? note: I am using the `Ent` framework

```golang
   err = client.Basket.
        Query().
        Where(basket.ID(2)).
        WithProducts().
        QueryProducts().
        GroupBy("price").
        Aggregate(func(selector *sql.Selector) string {
            return sql.As(sql.Sum("price"), "price")
        }).Scan(ctx, &r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Aggregate` and `GroupBy` functions are the friends. [Aggregation | Ent](https://entgo.io/docs/aggregate/#group-by-edge)

I modified the code as given below and got a very optimized `SQL` query, thanks to the Ent team.

```golang
err := client.Basket.
        Query().
        Where(basketEntity.ID(ID)).
        GroupBy(basketEntity.FieldID).
        Aggregate(func(s *sql.Selector) string {
            t := sql.Table(product.Table)
            joinT := sql.Table(basketEntity.ProductsTable)
            s.Join(joinT).
                On(s.C(basketEntity.FieldID), joinT.C(basketEntity.ProductsPrimaryKey[0]))
            s.Join(t).
                On(t.C(product.FieldID), joinT.C(basketEntity.ProductsPrimaryKey[1]))
            return sql.As(sql.Sum(t.C(product.FieldPrice)), "price")
        }).
        Aggregate(repository.Count()).
        Scan(ctx, &report)
```

The generated `SQL`:

```sql
SELECT "baskets"."id", SUM("t2"."price") AS "price", COUNT(*) 
FROM "baskets" 
JOIN "basket_products" AS "t1" ON "baskets"."id" = "t1"."basket_id" 
JOIN "products" AS "t2" ON "t2"."id" = "t1"."product_id" 
WHERE "baskets"."id" = $1 
GROUP BY "baskets"."id" args=[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try changing `GroupBy("price")` to `GroupBy(Basket.FieldPrice)`
i.e. referencing the fields by generated field name.
The example Group By Edge should be similar https://entgo.io/docs/aggregate/